# How to use an objects attribute as method parameter to set a map key?

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I would like to have a method that maps a List to a NavigableMap. The method call expects an parameter that is used as map key. This parameter is an attribute of the list objects.

Something like this, so both calls are ok:

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

NavigableMap<String, MyObject> stringKeyMap = asNavMap(list, MyObject:.getString());
NavigableMap<Date, MyObject>   dateKeyMap   = asNavMap(list, MyObject::getDate());
```

**I dont know how to define the second parameter (`MyObject::getDate()`). Do I have to use a lambda expression (`p -> p.getDate()`) or something like Predicate or Function?**

I've tried to derive a solution from Approach 8 (or simular) from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html, but I don't know how to do.

This is what I have done so far:

The concrete implementation:

```
public class ConcreteConverter {

    public static NavigableMap<Integer, Pair<Integer, String>> asNavMap(List<Pair<Integer, String>> pairs) {
        NavigableMap<Integer, Pair<Integer, String>> navMap = new TreeMap<>();
        for (Pair<Integer, String> pair : pairs) {
            navMap.put(pair.getKey(), pair);
        }
        return navMap;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Pair<Integer, String>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
        pairs.add(new Pair<Integer, String>(1, "one"));

        NavigableMap<Integer, Pair<Integer, String>> map = ConcreteConverter.asNavMap(pairs);
    }
}

class Pair<K, V> {
    K   key;
    V   val;
    // constructor, getter, setter
}
```

Here I stuck (??? is an attribute of the Pair object):

```
public static <K, V> NavigableMap<K, V> asNavMap(List<V> items, ???) {
    NavigableMap<K, V> navMap = new TreeMap<>();
        for (V item : items) {
            navMap.put(???, item);
        }
        return navMap;
}
```

Please notice I have barely experiences writing generic methods or using lambda functions/interfaces.

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit 1**

As Nick Vanderhofen mentioned I didn't clarify the search for a generic solution.

Comment: Drop the parentheses.

Comment: You mean `MyObject::getDate`? And how to define the method signature and key assignment?

Comment: Can you specify if two `MyObject` can have the same date or string ? If so, how to handle the duplicate key conflict ? Keep one ? Merge them ?

Comment: They can't. If they do it's an error in my data model. ;) I have several lists containing custom data types and I don't want to create a converter method for each type and I want to use the floor method of NavigalbeMap. That's why I am searching for a generic method and why I need several divergent key types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out a working solution!

Still reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach7 I've tried to use `Function`, and now this is my solution:

```
public static <K, V> NavigableMap<K, V> asNavigableMap(List<V> items, Function<V, K> mapper) {
  NavigableMap<K, V> navMap = new TreeMap<>();
  for (V item : items)
    navMap.put(mapper.apply(item), item);
  return navMap;
}
```

And these calls work:

```
List<Pair<Integer, String>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
pairs.add(new Pair<Integer, String>(1, "one"));

NavigableMap<Integer, Pair<Integer, String>> navI2P1 = GenericConverter.asNavigableMap(pairs, Pair::getKey);
NavigableMap<String, Pair<Integer, String>> navI2P2 = GenericConverter.asNavigableMap(pairs, Pair::getVal);
```

It was hard for me to understand the `Function` functional interface and the apply method.

Thanks to anyone!

Comment: Congratulations! Since your solution is exactly in line with my answer I hope you will accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a Function. You keep the code you wanted:

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

NavigableMap<String, MyObject> stringKeyMap = asNavMap(list, MyObject::getKey);
```

The method asNavMap can then take a Function:

```
private NavigableMap<String,MyObject> asNavMap(List<MyObject> list, Function<MyObject, String> getKey) {
   //the actual mapping goes here
}
```

The getKey method you are specifying can either be a simple getter on the MyObject:

```
public String getKey(){
    return key;
}
```

Or you could create a static method to get the same result:

```
public static String getKey(MyObject myObject){
    return myObject.getKey();
}
```

To apply the function you can just use the `apply` method:

```
String key = getKey.apply(someObject);
```

For the actual mapping implementation you can keep your for loop, or you could rewrite it using java 8 and re-use the Function that you got as a parameter in the collector. However, since you want a TreeMap, the syntax is quite verbose:

```
items.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(mapper, Function.identity(), (a,b) -> a, TreeMap::new));
```

Comment: Ups, hi Nick, answered in parallel. :D Thanks for your solution! But it is still an concrete implementation, and I would like to have a generic method. And one of the problems was the mapping (your comment `//mapping goes here`). But anyway, thank you very much, it is very closed to the wanted solution!

Comment: I left that out since you had that code already, you can also rewrite that for loop a little bit with Java 8, hang on and I'll show you

Comment: I'll hang on, interested in any solution.

Comment: Actually I tried to explain how to pass a Function to a method, since your question was how to pass the second parameter. I added an example of how to use collectors for creating the TreeMap. Actually I think it's pretty verbose, so the traditional for each loop is maybe better in this case.

Comment: Correct, I didn't emphasize sufficiently the generic way but I thougt my stucking example does. Sorry! Right now still experimenting with your stream example to get it working ...